# JPlayer not playing only in Firefox using JSONP

Tags: firefox, jsonp, mime-types, jplayer

I am using JSONP to wrap the JSON response.  Works fine in Chrome, IE and Safari.

The MIMEtype from the PHP script I am referencing is sending 
Content-Type:text/html

which may be the issue as I found this answer

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jplayer/Bv5fUoXqgew

here it is 
http://www.freeenergymedia.com/shared/PLAYER/player/player.html

Comment: Why not send something else then?

Comment: Ive had jquery conflict issues that only showed up in some browsers in the past before.  If you can't think of anything else it might be worth your time to try turning off/commmenting out other jquery/javascript plugins.

Comment: it's a widget, meant to cut and paste into different browsers. this example has no other jquery plugins.

Comment: I will check for JQuery conflict issues as I am using an AJAX script with JPlayer

Comment: your player works for me in Chrome, have you fixed it now?

Comment: The problem was in Firefox, but yes I fixed it, the issue was with an extra MIMEtype of ogg in the supplied: parameter of JPlayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed this

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $.getJSON("http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php?callback=?", {},function (json) 
    {

        new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, json, {
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "mp3, ogg",
            wmode: "window"
        });
    })
});
```

to this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


        $.getJSON("http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php?callback=?", {},function (json) 
        {

            new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
            }, json, {
                swfPath: "js",
                supplied: "mp3",
                wmode: "window"
            });
        })
    });
```